# Can setting the 'clustered' property of a Quartz setup cause problems on a single machine?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cluster-computing

We have a bunch of quartz jobs configured for running in a clustered environment and everything seems to work fine on the real cluster (two WAS machines).

In the DEV environment we still used

```
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
```

although we only use a single machine. But we get often but not always the following exception:

```
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: 
    Couldn't store trigger 'DEFAULT.MT_6uclr3emepk6p' for '<group>.<name>' 
    job:The job (<group>.<name>) referenced by the trigger does not exist.
```

We changed the setup for the DEV environment to

```
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false
```

This seemed to make the problem go away.

So the questions are:

- Is it a problem to set `org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true` when you aren't actually using a cluster
- if so why?
- if not what might be the reason for the original problem?

**UPDATE: Clarification on when the error occurs:**

This is the snippet that sets up the job.

```
JobKey JOBKEY = new JobKey("Name", "group");
newTrigger().withIdentity("TriggerName", "group").forJob(
                JOBKEY).build();
JobDetail job = newJob(NameJob.class).withIdentity(
                JOBKEY)
                .storeDurably().build();
scheduler.addJob(job, false);
```

This snippet is supposed to trigger a job execution

```
scheduler.triggerJob(JOBKEY);
```

Comment: What version of Quartz are you using?
When do you get these errors on creating a new trigger for an existing Job? Or creating a new job and trigger? Or perhaps on update?

Comment: quartz-scheduler is version 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a red herring.    isClustered=true with one node is just fine (though unnecessary).

I'll bet you were running into problems caused by multiple developers using the same database, while doing their tests/builds concurrently.

Comment: Not likely. Our dev machine get a nightly deployment, and a UI Actions is supposed to trigger a job run, which fails with the exception.

Comment: Well, not sure what you ran into then, but it's not a problem related to the isClustered flag being = true when you have only one node. The error message means that the identified job (the one you are trying to trigger) doesn't exist in the scheduler.